# How to properly add an image programmatically in a customcell objective-c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I'm trying to add an image programmatically in a custom `tableviewcell` but it display it like this:

[image: 1]

I would like it like this:

[image: 2] (like a notification)

Here is my code:

ViewController.m

```
@implementation albumsSingerVC

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    _matableview.delegate = self;
    _matableview.dataSource = self;
}

- ( nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"customCell";
        
      customCellSingersAlbumVC *cell = (customCellSingersAlbumVC*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        
      if (cell == nil)
      {
          [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"customCellSingersAlbumView" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    
                 
      }
cell = (customCellSingersAlbumVC *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier]; 

    UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    UIImage *myimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pink.png"];
    imageview.image=myimg;
    imageview.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 150, 150); //I also 
changed the values to a small ones.
    [[cell imageView ] addSubview:imageview]; 
   
    return cell;
    
}
    
@end
```

I tried it with differents syntax.

I also tried to do it different :

customCell.m:

```
@implementation customCellSingersAlbumVC

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    
    UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    UIImage *myimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pink.png"];
    imageview.image=myimg;
    imageview.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 150, 150);
    [self.contentView addSubview:imageview];
    
}

@end
```

but `viewdidload` is never triggered.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: hi @Adriaan sorry I didn't know

Comment: No problem, just be sure to post the answer below! Instead of editing your question, copy-paste it in the dialogue below "Your Answer" (just down here from the comment section) and press "Post Your Answer" to post it. That way Stack Overflow is more easily searchable, since questions go in questions, and answers in answers.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I finally found how to do it here is the code if someone is interested:

```
    - ( nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"customCell";
            
          customCellSingersAlbumVC *cell = (customCellSingersAlbumVC*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
            
          if (cell == nil)
          {
              [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"customCellSingersAlbumView" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        
                     
          }
        cell = (customCellSingersAlbumVC *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        
        // Create a new UIImage object
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pink.png"];
    
        // Create a new image view 
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    
        // Set the image view's frame to the desired size
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(95, 10, 30, 30);
    
        // Create a new label object
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20)];
    
        // Set the label's text
        label.text = @"  6";
      //  imageView.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor;
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width /2;
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0;
    
        // Add the image view to your table view cell's content view
        [imageView addSubview:label];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
      
       
        return cell;
        
    }
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't as helpful as they could be. It would be best if your answer clearly explained what was wrong and how the code in the answer solves the issue.

Comment: You shouldn't add subviews in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Cells are reused, so as you scroll you'll be adding more and more duplicate subviews. Instead, you should design your cell *with those elements already there* and then either show or hide them as needed in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.